# PhpStorm : Navigate to class file or symbol troubleshooting

Tags: phpstorm

In PhpStorm, I'm trying to navigate to a class by name or file name (shortcuts Ctrl-N and Ctrl-Shift-N) but the popup window never appears.
Same problem while going through menus : Navigate > Class and Navigate > File. No effect at all.

I'm under Debian Jessie, Gnome Shell (3.14), PhpStorm 8.0.1

Any suggestion is welcome, thx a lot !

Comment: What GUI theme do you use (in PhpStorm)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to another GUI Theme -- this happens with Darcula and Gnome 3.14 (3.12 was reported to be OK).

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-130732

Comment: Thx a lot. I guess I'll need to change theme :(

Comment: Let's hope it's temporarily (regardless of who will fix it .. but I personally do not expect JB to work hard on this as prev Gnome worked ok). Any chance to update to newer Gnome Shell? Maybe the issue is no longer there (sorry, not a Linux guy here).